# call fetch requests synchronously using promises

Tags: javascript, fetch

I would like to call fetch for each item in an array, but I would like to do them one at a time, only starting a new one when the previous one has finished. ***Is there a way to solve this using promises only?*** I solved it using recursion, but I think my solution is a bit silly. My solution is as follows:

```js
//call fetch once for each word in the array
let promises = "words to fetch from this array".split(' ')
fetchCall(promises.shift())

function fetchCall(word) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('this is simulating a fetch call')
    setTimeout(function() {
      return resolve('resolved')
    }, 1000)

  }).then(function() {
    //only make the next fetch call when the previous one has finished
    if (promises.length > 0) {
      fetchCall(promises.shift())
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my lovely async for each

```
async function asyncForEach(array, promiseFn) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await promiseFn(array[index], index, array)
  }
}
```

```
//call fetch once for each word in the array
let promises = "words to fetch from this array".split(' ')
```

Then call `asyncForEach` for your array

```
await asyncForEach(promises, item => {
  // add async to simulate delay from xhr request
  return new Promise( async function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('this is simulating a fetch call')
    await setTimeout(function(){
      return resolve('resolved')
    }, 1000)
    
  }).then(function(){
    // print item after promise resolve
    console.log(item);
  })
})
```

OR
You can use Promise.all

```
//call fetch once for each word in the array
let promises = "words to fetch from this array".split(' ')


let promisesArr = promises.map(e => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('this is simulating a fetch call', e)
    resolve(e)
  }, 1000)
}))

// res is array or resolve arguments 
Promise.all(promisesArr).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Unfortunately `promise.all` performs the fetch operations in parallel, while the question is asking how to perform them sequentially, one after another..

Comment: @traktor, yep( I forgot about it( my first variant is perfectly work with queue

Comment: Agreed, `async` functions and `await` would be the normal coding method to invoke promise processing indirectly. I like the `callback` argument as it solves a problem the posted code suffers from which the OP may not have considered yet.